# Does pisteuō mean Believe or obey?

Tags: gospel-of-john, faith

pisteu heard that pisteuō means to obey. But that passive tense of pistis means to believe. Accordingly John seems to use active tense pisteuō rather than Pistis in his gospel. If this is true then should most of
the translations in John be about obeying in Jesus rather than simply
obeying Him?
With reference to people, pisteuo means to obey (Soph., OT, 625)
For example

> > ”He came as a witness, to bear witness about the light, that all might believe through him.“
> > ‭‭John‬ ‭1‬:‭7‬ ‭ESV‬‬

Should this be translated as obey instead?